# Merging citations

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, citations

In MS Word 2016, is there a way to create multiple citations that will appear within a single set of brackets, i.e. using IEEE style?

For example [1-3] instead of [1][2][3].

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround as detailed [here](https://superuser.com/a/1427201/741816).

Just select the text of the related citation numbers and bookmark it, and then cross-reference that bookmark.