# Merging citations in MS Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, citations

In MS Word 2007, when I add three citations in a document, it shows up as

```
[1,2,3]
```

Is there any way to merge it so that it shows up like shown below?

```
[1-3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a work-around. Just select the text of the related citation numbers and bookmark it, and then cross-reference that bookmark,

where the bookmark is done by:
[alt](/questions/tagged/alt)+[i](/questions/tagged/i)+[k](/questions/tagged/k) (Autohotkey code: Send !ik)

and the cross-reference is done by:
[alt](/questions/tagged/alt)+[n](/questions/tagged/n)+[r](/questions/tagged/r) (Autohotkey code: Send !nr)
then go to the "Bookmark" reference type.

For instance my automatically-generated bibliography shows something like this:

```
[1] Citation 1
[2] Citation 2
[3] Citation 3
```

I select the text 1 within [1] and name the bookmark as "Citation_1_merge",
and then select the text 3 within [3] and name the bookmark as "Citation_3_merge".
Then in the crossreference I insert the bookmarked entries to get 1 and 3, with the "[", "-", and "]" typed in manually to get the result of

```
[1-3]
```

**NOTE / CAVEAT:** This method works best when you bookmark static text, i.e.: citations are finalized in the document. Otherwise, doing a [ctrl](/questions/tagged/ctrl)+[a](/questions/tagged/a) -> [f9](/questions/tagged/f9) update will eliminate these bookmarks.